# Is there any plug-in or method that saves passwords for excel and/or word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-manager, microsoft-word

As I stated in the question, I need such plug-in since I'm dealing with password protected excel and word files and these passwords are mostly same but long and complicated. Such plug-in will save lots of time. Also note that Winrar has such built-in functionality. I need exactly like that.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I need like in the picture:

[image]

Like in the winrar:

[image]

Comment: Why not simply use a standard password manager?

Comment: Like what? And this can be applied to excel and word?

Comment: Pretty much any standalone password manager will do. They're ultimately unaware of what are the passwords for, often websites but they can be literally anything, including Office files.

Comment: The files are coming from others, with password protection already. So in this case, I need a manager that remembers passwords inside word/excel window. Can you know a manager like that? If so, please post it then

Comment: That won't matter. If the "protected" file comes from others, then the others need to provide the password together with the file, and you need to input it somewhere at least once. Any kind of password manager (within Offce or not) can remember previously entered password, but not completely unknown ones.

Comment: @Alejandro I updated the question. Can you look at it? I don't think that 3rd party password manager can manage inside protection of word/excel other than a plug-in. If there is such manager, please post the name of it in an answer.

Comment: Effectively, I also think that rules out any serious password manager, leaving plugins as the only option. This however don't solves the problem that you must input the password at least the very first time as you received the file.

Comment: I know passwords and I input them the very first time, but I don't want to input the passwords in the second, third etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Keepass 2

I recommend storing all of your passwords with [Keepass 2](https://keepass.info/), not just the passwords for these documents.

Here's a way to get Keepass to open the file and enter the password for you:

1. For each file, create a new entry in KeePass with the folder path as the UserName; e.g. `C:\Inconspicuous\NefariousSchemes.docx` or `C:\Users\SecretAgent\MissleLaunchCodes.xlsx`.
2. Put the password in the Password field.
3. For the URL, put this command for Excel files:

   ```
   cmd://powershell.exe -command "(New-Object -comobject Excel.application).Workbooks.Open('{UserName}',0,0,5,'{Password}').parent.visible = $true"
   ```

   ...and this command for Word documents:

   ```
   cmd://powershell.exe -command "(New-Object -comobject Word.application).Documents.open('{UserName}',$null,$false,$null,'{Password}').parent.visible = $true"
   ```

[image: Edit User name, Password, and URL fields in Keepass entry]

Once this is done, you can open any of these password-protected files by selecting the entry in Keepass and hitting Ctrl+U to run the command stored in the **U**rl field.

[image: Right-click or Ctrl+U to open URL for a given KeePass entry]